# How can i connect children to same parents with d3.js in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to develop a pedigree chart with d3.js

```
  const data = [
{ id: 1, name: "John", children: [3], spouse: 11, gender: "male" },
{ id: 2, name: "Jane", children: [3], gender: "female" },
{ id: 3, name: "Bob", fatherId: 1, motherId: 2, children: 5, gender: "male" },
```

];

```
const stratify = d3
.stratify()
.id((d) => d.id)
.parentId((d) => d.children);


const formattedData = stratify(data);

const tree = d3.tree().size([900, 500]);

const _data = tree(formattedData);
```

how can I and another child and connect with same parents

```
{ id: 4, name: "ben", fatherId: 1, motherId: 2, children: null, gender: "male" }
```

When add this data, it is giving a stratify error of multiple roots, so i created a root node, to solve this issue but when I draw the chart it is create separate parents for
both ben and bob

How do i connect bod and ben to same parents

[image]